# make an app appear in share panel to accept selected text from other apps

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uiactivityviewcontroller

I'm writing an app in iOS which handles text. Normally users can enter in their own text via a text area but I would also users like to be able to highlight text in other apps (e.g. mail, websites etc.) and allow users to send text via selection and the share panel where my app would then appear? Can I do this in iOS and if so how? Is this like the reverse of UIActivityViewController?

*An example from my phone. I'm on a website, see phrase which is interesting, I select it, and then send it to Notes from the text highlighting share option. Notes is an Apple app but I could also send it to other third party apps such as Twitter or WhatsApp. I would like my app to also appear on this shared list and be able to receive and process the text.*

Comment: Missed out the word users to say that it is the users who would highlight the text in the other app. This naturally changes the nature of the problem: added an related example in italics to make it clearer.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is to add an app extension with a `Share` extension type to your app. You can read more on app extensions here to get started.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/Share.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH12-SW1

Answer (score 0):

It is not generally possible for apps to communicate directly with each other in iOS and certainly not possible for one app to highlight text in another app.  Apple deliberately "sandbox" apps to prevent one interfering with another.

If you want text from another app to appear in yours then the user will need to manually copy and paste the text.

Further details on what inter-app communication is possible is given on the Apple web site: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/Inter-AppCommunication/Inter-AppCommunication.html .

Comment: Many thanks for this. It is very helpful. I suspect that you are indeed right. For the first point, embarrassingly, I realise I made a mistake in my initial draft by omitting to say that the user would have to highlight the text they wished to share in the 'other' app not my code. I've done things like this in past with routes for navigation programmes but they are for some reason URL based. WhatsApp and Twitter appear to be able to do it also with text but I don't know how.